# Exception in thread Julia sets

Tags: java, ioexception

I'm writing a program to generate a Julia set in java, and I've run into an issue with saving the output images. I've managed to get it to compile, but upon running and inputting the prompts, I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Julia.main(Julia.java:132)
```

And here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math.*;

import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;

public class Julia{

public static void saveImage( BufferedImage img, File file ) throws IOException {

    ImageWriter      writer = null;
    java.util.Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");

    if( iter.hasNext() ){
        writer = (ImageWriter)iter.next();
    }

    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream( file );
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    ImageWriteParam param = new JPEGImageWriteParam( java.util.Locale.getDefault() );
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT) ;
    param.setCompressionQuality(0.98f);

    writer.write(null, new IIOImage( img, null, null ), param);

}

public static BufferedImage Julia(  ) 

{

//z= (Xmin +i(Xmax- Xmin) /size) + (Ymin+ j(Ymax-Ymin)/size);
    BufferedImage outImage;
    float zreal, zimag;
    float cReal, cImag;  
    float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
    int height, width, size;
    height = width = size = 512;
    outImage = new BufferedImage( width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR );

    cReal = 0;
    cImag = 0;
    xMin = 0;
    xMax = 0;
    yMin = 0;
    yMax = 0;

    //c= creal+cimag
    Complex c;
     c = new Complex (cReal, cImag);

    //z = z^2;
    //f= z^2 +c;

int i, j ,k;
Complex f;

for (i = 0; i<width; i++)
    {
    for(j = 0; j<height; j++)
        {
        for (k= 0; k< 256; k++)
            {
        zreal = (xMin +i*(xMax- xMin) /size);
        zimag = (yMin+ j*(yMax-yMin)/size);
        Complex z = new Complex( zreal, zimag);

        z = z.multi(z);
        f = z.addd(c);

        if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(zreal, 2.0)+Math.pow(zimag, 2.0))>2)
            break;
            }

    int pixel = getHSBColor(k);
    outImage.setRGB(i, j, pixel);
        }

    }

    return( outImage );

}

public static void main(String[] args)

{
    BufferedImage outImage, julia;
    double cReal, cImag;  
    float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
    String fname = null;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Input: cReal cImag xMin xMax yMin yMax fname");
    cReal=scan.nextDouble ();
    cImag=scan.nextDouble ();
    xMin=scan.nextFloat ();
    xMax=scan.nextFloat ();
    yMin=scan.nextFloat ();
    yMax=scan.nextFloat ();
    fname = scan.next(); 


    double f;
    int z;
    int c;
    int height, width, size;
    height = width = size = 512;

    outImage = Julia();  // Put 6 junk inside cReal, cImag, xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax


    try{
    julia  = Julia ();
//132// saveImage( julia,  new File( "Julia" + args[0] ) );
    } catch (IOException e){

}
}
// hsb color table
public static int getHSBColor(int idx)
{
    return Color.getHSBColor((float)(idx/255.0), 1.0f, 1.0f).getRGB();
}


}

class Complex 
{
double real;
double imaginary;

Complex(double newReal, double newImaginary)
{

    real = newReal;
    imaginary = newImaginary;
}

public Complex addd(Complex complexToAdd)
{
    double x , y , newreal, newimaginary;

    newreal = complexToAdd.real;
    newimaginary = complexToAdd.imaginary;
    x = real + newreal;
    y = imaginary + newimaginary;
    Complex newComplex = new Complex(x, y);

    return newComplex;
}

public Complex multi(Complex complexToMulti)
{

    double x, y , newreal, newimaginary;


    newreal = complexToMulti.real;
    newimaginary = complexToMulti.imaginary;

    x = real*newreal - imaginary*newimaginary;
    y = real*newimaginary + imaginary*newreal;

    Complex newComplex= new Complex(x, y);

    return newComplex;
}


}
```

I think my issue is that I'm having trouble with the try/catch blocks, but I'm not entirely sure about that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please indicate what line 132 is.

Comment: I hashed out the line and lead with 132. //132// saveImage( julia,  new File( "Julia" + args[0] ) ); it's inside of my try catch block

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not an issue with the try-catch blocks. An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is an exception that shows a bug in a program. You should never (need to) catch such exceptions.

In this case you access the position 0 of the array `args`, although the array is empty. You should check for this first and take the appropriate actions. Probably your program should check whether `args` is empty, show a message to the user that it needs a file name as parameter, and exit.

A hint for your try-catch block: You should never leave it completely empty. If your program fails to write the file, it will just ignore the failure, and you will end up wondering why strange things are happening. At the very least, you should put `e.printStackTrace()` into the catch block, so that you are notified when something bad happens. In real programs, for `IOExceptions` you would usually show a message to the user (and log it) that says something like `"File saving failed (" + e.getMessage() + ")"`. This is more user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the command line arguments you pass to the `java` process when running class `Julia`. It looks like you're not passing any argument, even though your code expects there to be at least 1 argument (`args[0]`).

Also, I'd like to make a side note to your code: it's very, very bad practice in Java to declare a static method with the same name as the class it is stored in. In fact, it's bad practice to name any other method except the constructors in this way. Moreover, any other method but the constructors should start with non-capitalized letter.